# The getter 'create' isn't defined for the type 'flutter class'

Tags: firebase, flutter, navigation

I'm using Flutter and I've been used the the class Routes to navigate between views but a the IDE throw the next error:
error: The getter 'create' isn't defined for the type 'UserLogin'.
here is the code:

```
class Routes{
  static const login = '/';
  static const registra = '/registra';
  static const home = '/home';
  static const info = '/info';
  static const incons = '/incons';


  static Route routes(RouteSettings routeSettings){
    switch(routeSettings.name){
      case login:
        return _buildRoute(UserLogin.create);
      case registra:
        return _buildRoute(EmailCreate.create);
      case home:
        return _buildRoute(HomeMenu.create);
      case info:
        return _buildRoute(UserInfoMenu.create);
      case incons:
        return _buildRoute(IssuesContainer.create);
      default:
        throw Exception('Route does not exists');
    }
  }

  static MaterialPageRoute _buildRoute(Function build)=> MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>build(context));

}
```

Im importing all the classes that im using, but the only that doesn't throw any error is the EmailCreate one

I attach the implementation of the class Routes:

```
final _navigatorkey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  static Widget create(){
    return BlocListener<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      listener: (context, state){
        if (state is AuthSignedOut){
          _navigatorkey.currentState?.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Routes.login, (route) => false);
        }else if (state is AuthSignedIn){
          _navigatorkey.currentState?.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(Routes.home, (route) => false);
        }
      },
      child: MyApp(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorkey,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      onGenerateRoute: Routes.routes,
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know if is it a better option use Navigator.push and Navigator.pop instead of Routes.

Comment: can you show the code for the following classes: `UserLogin`, `EmailCreate`, `HomeMenu`  `UserInfoMenu` and `IssuesContainer`?

Answer (score 0):

> The getter 'create' isn't defined for the type 'UserLogin'

This means you do not have a `create` method/getter for the UserLogin class.

The error will go away when you add a static method `create` to the class.

Comment: That works, thank you! 